# Is there an ambiguity in the expression "more rigorous rules"?

Tags: grammar

Is there an ambiguity in the sentence

> Young people today have to learn **more rigorous rules** than their
> ancestors.

I think the sentence seems to be interpreted in two ways:

1. more rules that are rigorous
2. a more rigorous set of rules

How to rewrite the sentence to avoid ambiguity?

Comment: There is some ambiguity, but in practice almost everyone will interpret the sentence as having the more likely meaning: i.e. rules that are more rigorous - rules that demand more of the rule taker - than the rules that applied in the past.  If you wanted to emphasise the number of rules, you'd probably put it differently. You might just shorten it to "more rules"!

If on the other hand what you mean is the second, more obvious of your two interpretations, then I doubt there there'd be any need to re-write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an ambiguity here. Most people would assume meaning 2. You can resolve it by using a post-modifying phrase

> Young people today have to learn rules that are more rigorous than the rules their ancestors had to learn. (giving meaning 2)

or by paraphrasing "more"

> Young people today have to learn a greater number of rigorous rules than their ancestors. (giving meaning 1)

However, most people would prefer the shorter expression. The default understanding is the same, and the double meaning may be intentional:

> There are more rules for young people today, and those rules are more rigorous.